# Can I get by without a panel?

Tags: gnome-panel, network-manager

I feel  my panel is pretty redundant. I use gnome-do as a launcher and I use exposé to check what windows I have open. The only thing in there that I need a panel for is Network Manager/Notifications. Is there a way of managing notifications without having any visible "bar"?

Answer (score 3):

[StaloneTray](http://stalonetray.sourceforge.net/) will let you add a notification area to your desktop. It's quite light and it's used often with minimalist WMs.

I have used it in the past and it did its work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see your network notifications through libnotify messages.The only thing I think you'll miss is your network status, which you can check via command line if required. You may want to ensure that Alt-F2 works for 'run', or that you have some other method of re-launching Gnome-Do if it crashes (which it does occasionally). In the worst case, there's always ctrl-alt-F1 to switch to a console.

Answer (score 0):

Try Wicd, you can manage network without a panel. For the sound, you can manage it with keyboard for a lots of laptops. Is that what you are searching for ?